# Warning "It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK."

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, warnings, google-cloud-cdn, browser-console

Currently I am getting a warning :

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-<PACKAGE>.js
```

I have gone through several related links to this problem but even after following all their solutions, I am not able to remove the error. 
As the description says to use the given link with the name of the component I am using. I have included the links which I need, still I see the warning.

I have even tried to include all the links given in Firebase website, still I see it.

Currently I am only using Firebase Realtime Database, but while creating firebase init using CMD, I had included Functions, Hosting, Storage and Database.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

I have even tried changing the versions from 5.0.0 to 5.4.0, but no use.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved it by adding two scripts.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.2/firebase-database.js"></script>`

Comment: I made the changes suggested and was still getting warning. Turns out, I was importing firebase twice. Make sure you not importing it somewhere else as well. (with import statement not script includes)